# Tool for dynamically plotting and viewing many complex functions

Tags: linux, graphs, data-analysis, plotting

#### Situation

I'm searching for a tool or a programming library that can plot many complex functions (Examples below) as created-on-the-fly *interactive* graph. So kind of how game rendering works: There are given functions, that describe how everything looks, but only the small portion, that is shown on screen will really be evaluated.

( I have difficulties explaining this concisely and good. I appreciate if someone can help me improving the question)

#### Example plot

[image]

#### Example functions

Below are some simplified examples of the functions I'm plotting.

```
f1(x):
 return x*2`
```

```
 f2(x):
   if (x > 20):
     return 1
   return 0
```

```
 f3(x):
   if (f2 (x) >= 0):
     return 1
   return 0
```

#### Constraints

- OS: Linux

  - (for the sake of completeness, feel free to mention other plattforms as well)
- Cost: free is welcome, paid is ok

#### What I've tried

For plotting in general I've used Python + numpy + plotly (for gaining interactive plots). However, with a worst case of about 946,080,000 data points and 50+ functions, this became quite unfeasable.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Kmplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KmPlot). Used it myself.
From wikipedia:

> KmPlot is a mathematical function plotter for the KDE Desktop. It has a powerful built-in parser. The graphs can be colorized and the view is scalable, so that you are able to zoom to the level you need. Users can plot different functions simultaneously and combine them to build new functions. It also provides some numerical and visual features like:
>
> - Filling and calculating the area between the plot and the first axis
> - Finding maximum and minimum values
> - Changing function parameters dynamically
> - Plotting derivatives and integral functions.